# Rails update related model data in update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such code:

```
def update
    @oil = Oil.find(params[:id])
    @product_types = ProductType.all    
    if @oil.update_attributes(params[:oil])
      if @oil.other_products_cross_lists.update_attributes(:cross_value => @oil.model.to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "").upcase)
        redirect_to admin_oils_path
      end
    else
      render :layout => 'admin'
    end
  end
```

but when i run it i get:

```
undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f7fb4cdc220>
```

and my other_products_cross_lists isn't updated... Also i try update_attribute and get the same error.

What i do wrong?

Also when i run my destroy method

```
def destroy
    @oil = Oil.find(params[:id])
    if @oil.destroy
      if @oil.other_products_cross_lists.destroy
        redirect_to admin_oils_path
      end
    else
      render :layout => 'admin'
    end
  end
```

other_products_cross_lists  didn't destroy...

How can i solve this problem?

model:

```
class Oil < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_products_cross_lists, :foreign_key => 'main_id'

class OtherProductsCrossList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :oil
```

Comment: can you post the model definition of `Oil` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

other_products_cross_lists is an association on your Oil model.
You cannot use update_attributes on an Array or ActiveRecord:Relation object.

What you should do is

```
@oil.other_products_cross_lists.each {|list| list.update_attributes(:cross_value => @oil.model.to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "").upcase)}
```

for destroying

you can use

`@oil.other_products_cross_lists.delete_all`

or

```
@oil.other_products_cross_lists.destroy_all
```

You should check out the difference between delete_all and destroy_all for clarity.

Comment: oh, ok)  also maybe it would be easier to write one more find for selecting other_products_cross_lists related?

Comment: calling other_products_cross_lists on your @oil object is perfectly fine.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much. I have struggled with this half of the day when trying to update columns in an Active Record Relational Object. Your answer saves my job :D

Answer (score 0):

as the error says `other_products_cross_lists` is a relation (I assume your model `oil` has_many `other_products_cross_lists`).

`update_attribute` is a method of an instance of a model, not a method of a relation.

I don't really understand, what you want to do with you `update_attribute`, but if user nested_attributes, then

```
@oil.update_attributes(params[:oil])
```

takes care of updating the relation.

Also, if you define your relation beween `Oil` and `OtherProducts` as `dependend: :destroy` Rails handles the removel of dependent records.